# jpa mapping on three tables that are associated with foreign key

Tags: spring-data-jpa, associations

i have below 3 tables

Table A:         Table B:                      Table C:
id               TableA id(foreign key)        id
type             TableC id(foreign key)        name

i have requirement where i have to fetch everything from tableA but when i fetch i have to fetch the name associated from Table C based on the mapping from TableB.

it's a oneToOne mapping. i tried adding Embeddable , joincolumn but nothing works.
i was referring this link - https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/ and implemented same but still no luck.
how would i achieve this through spring boot JPA?

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Could you please post the entities in question or the exact DB DDL/structure? Reading your description does not give a clear idea how exactly the tables are interconnected

Comment: sure, please find my below tables

Comment: create table GSP.TICKET_TYPES  (
   ID                   NUMBER                          not null,
   NAME                 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
   PARTNER_MANDATORY    NUMBER,
   CONTRACT_MANDATORY   NUMBER,
   ASSET_MANDATORY      NUMBER,
   INTERNAL_TICKET      NUMBER,
   FORM_COMPONENT       VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
   UI_CREATION_ALLOWED  NUMBER,
   DEFAULT_COMMENTS     VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR),
   DEFAULT_RESPONSIBLE  VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
   DEFAULT_GROUP_ASSIGNEE VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
   ADDON_PARTNER_REQUIRED NUMBER,
   constraint PK_TICKET_TYPES primary key (ID)
);

Comment: Table 2 create table GSP.TICKET_GROUPS  (
   ID                   NUMBER                          not null,
   NAME                 VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
   constraint PK_TICKET_GROUPS primary key (ID)
);

Comment: create table GSP.TICKET_TYPES_GROUPS  (
   TICKET_TYPE_ID       NUMBER                          not null,
   TICKET_GROUP_ID      NUMBER                          not null,
   constraint PK_TICKET_TYPES_GROUPS primary key (TICKET_TYPE_ID, TICKET_GROUP_ID)
); this is mapping table where foreign key of above tables has been given

Comment: i want to fetch the ticketTypes data along with it's group name from ticket_groups tabels based on mapping given in the ticket-type_groups table